# CSS DIV word-wrap issue

Tags: css, html

I have a DIV that I want to use to display some formatted content in. However, I have problems with some text TAGs inside the DIV.
You can see my problem in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/3760/).
Can you please help me solve this?
I need the content of the second "column" to be able to word-wrap and when it would do that, I want the next "line" to be moved down so it would not overlap it.
Basically I want to text to look normal inside the DIV.

```
<div class="container-right">
    <div class="topul" style="background-color:#2ecc71; width:352px;"></div>
    <div class="parent" style="min-width:350px; width:350px; height:445px;">
        <p class="myp" style="color:#2ecc71; font-size:2em; margin-bottom:0px"> <b>Worker information</b>

        </p>
        <div class="topul2" style="float:left; background-color:#2ecc71;"></div>
        <div class="d-table">
            <div class="d-tablerow">
                <div class="d-tablecell" style="text-align:right; width:30%">
                    <p class="myp3" style="color:#2ecc71">Name:
                        <p>
                </div>
                <div class="d-tablecell" style="text-align:left; width:70%;">
                    <p class="myp4" style="color:#2ecc71"><b>Some name</b>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-tablerow">
                <div class="d-tablecell" style="text-align:right; width:30%">
                    <p class="myp3" style="color:#2ecc71;">Address:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="d-tablecell" style="text-align:left; width:70%;">
                    <p class="myp4" style="color:#2ecc71; display:inline-block"><b>Here goes a long text as address that does not word-wrap and exits the DIV</b>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="d-tablerow">
                <div class="d-tablecell" style="text-align:right; width:30%">
                    <p class="myp3" style="color:#2ecc71">Other info:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="d-tablecell" style="text-align:left; width:70%;">
                    <p class="myp4" style="color:#2ecc71; "><b>Here is other information</b>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the CSS in the jsfiddle link above.
I give up... I am a newbie with CSS and HTML and so far this is done manually by me after digging on google. But now I have no idea how to solve this.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Dude, this is extremely bad written code....

Comment: So I edited my original question with the fact that I added display:inline-block at the style of the "long text" and it appears that the word-wrapping occurs... sort-of... but still it goes beyond the div . Also I want the "Address" text to be aligned horizontally with the first line of the "long text". How can I do that?

Comment: I believe you mike-barwick. As I stated above, I am a newbie with CSS and HTML.

Comment: Why are you turning all the DIVS into tables??

Comment: The Main DIV (container-right) is part of a much larger picture (page). And I did not want to use tables per se... so I ended up making the alignments using this div-table mix

Comment: This is probably not the best use of display: table. Remove that stuff, and try again -- use things like text-align, and float.

Comment: Believe me, I tried that before ending up with this table stuff. It was a nightmare. Also I found a lot of links on the web recommending the usage of display-table, so I do not see the problem with this approach

Comment: Yeah...making your divs tables is like trying to incorporate the old school into the new. Super bad code man...don't do this. Not a good habit to pick up. You're going to run into a lot of problems...all this code needs to be rewrite IMO. Also, don't use inline styling (also old school)...that's what CSS is for...

Comment: display-table should only be used in very specific instances...not to code your site structure. Whoever told you that is wrong...

Comment: Thank you. I did not know of this. I am pretty new at this stuff, and I learn as I go. However your suggestions will definitely help be in the future. I learned a lot today. Thank you Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your .myp4 styles

To avoid the overlap remove height: 2px;

To avoid bleeding from the div set max-width: 200px;

As mentioned above set heights are a bit of a nightmare unless you're going for a specific look. It's better to use min-height or max-height

NOTE: You should seriously split all your CSS into a separate file rather than having them in the elements
Also is there a particular reason for you to use crazy displays? You could achieve the same effect easily by having a div wrapping two other divs that are float left. display: block; will give you less of a hard time if you're a newbie. Aim for less code, not more.

Comment: This almost works. I tried your suggestions, and ended up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/3765/ but I still don't see the "Address" aligned to the top of the "long text". How can I achieve that?

Comment: That's a property of tables, use vertical-align: top;

Comment: Thank you very much. You were most helpful.

Comment: Check out codecademy to get started with HTML, CSS and JS. It'll give you a good base (http://www.codecademy.com/)

Comment: I am not very happy about the resulted code, but it happened step-by-step :(. I am not very familiar with css, and I did not want to create a class or an ID for each element of the page (I tried to trim down the separate css... and ended up piling up in the HTML). I will try next time to use display-block instead of table, even though there are too many opinions about what to use and where and why. Thank you again. I learned a few things from you, and for that I am grateful. Have a good day

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation with codecademy. I will go through it, even though I am not that newbie. Still, maybe I will find things that I do not know there. Thanks

Comment: Dude...no offence....your code is newbie for sure. Pound the books and it'll all come together for you. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting min-height instead of height on the rows and/or cells.

Comment: I tryed that... no change. You can also do it in the jsfiddle to see for yourself

Answer (score 1):

The width of the table is the culprit, it's allowing its children to run wild on your page. .d-table {
width: 350px;
}